# Oracle Optimizer Unexpected Results

Tags: oracle

I have a co worker who wrote the following query. The first one works and the second one does not. Also if you remove the aggregate function from the subquery, it works. The oracle optimizer is doing something weird. Any thoughts? Running in SQL Developer 3.1 against 11.1.0.6.0 64 bit.

This works:

```
SELECT
  a.fd_customer_key
, b.fd_customer_key
, b.counter
FROM FETCH_CUSTOMER a
, (select fd_customer_key, count(*) as counter from fetch_customer_order group by fd_customer_key) b
where a.fd_customer_key = b.fd_customer_key (+)
and b.counter is null
```

This doesn’t:

```
SELECT
a.fd_customer_key
, b.fd_customer_key
, b.counter
FROM FETCH_CUSTOMER a
, (select fd_customer_key, count(*) as counter from fetch_customer_order group by fd_customer_key) b
 where a.fd_customer_key = b.fd_customer_key (+)
 and b.fd_customer_key is null
```

Comment: when we say it doesn't work, we mean that it is not returning any rows.

Comment: This also works `SELECT
  a.fd_customer_key
, b.fd_customer_key
FROM FETCH_CUSTOMER a
,(select fd_customer_key, 1 from fetch_customer_order group by fd_customer_key) b
where a.fd_customer_key = b.fd_customer_key (+)
and b.fd_customer_key is null;`

Comment: This does not work `SELECT
  a.fd_customer_key
, b.fd_customer_key
FROM FETCH_CUSTOMER a
,(select fd_customer_key, sum(1) from fetch_customer_order group by fd_customer_key) b
where a.fd_customer_key = b.fd_customer_key (+)
and b.fd_customer_key is null;`

Comment: Are you sure this isn't an Oracle bug? If you're getting weird inconsistent behaviour then a bug seems likely. There are lots of them out there. If it's a bug, you really need to contact Oracle support or your DBA.

Comment: See the answer from Vincent Malgrat below. If you take his example and put an index on table b you reproduce the error. The optimizer is doing something that may not be a bug but it is not expected behavior either (at least by us).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you are trying to make an anti-join (find the rows from `FETCH_CUSTOMER` that have no corresponding rows in `FETCH_CUSTOMER_ORDER`).

With Oracle you do not have to use this clever `OUTER JOIN` trick to write an anti-join, you could use a `NOT IN` or `NOT EXISTS` operator and let the optimizer find the best plan. This will be just as efficient and easier to read.

Anyway, I can't reproduce your findings, here's my setup:

```
CREATE TABLE a (ID NUMBER PRIMARY KEY);
CREATE TABLE b (a_id NUMBER NOT NULL, DATA VARCHAR2(30));
INSERT INTO a (SELECT object_id FROM all_objects);
INSERT INTO b (SELECT object_id, object_name 
                 FROM all_objects WHERE object_type = 'VIEW');

SELECT a.id, b.a_id, b.cnt
  FROM a, (SELECT a_id, COUNT(*) cnt FROM b GROUP BY a_id) b
 WHERE a.id = b.a_id (+)
   AND b.cnt IS NULL;

SELECT a.id, b.a_id, b.cnt
  FROM a, (SELECT a_id, COUNT(*) cnt FROM b GROUP BY a_id) b
 WHERE a.id = b.a_id (+)
   AND b.a_id IS NULL;
```

You will find that both queries return rows. What is your DB version?

Comment: I did try your above example and it does indeed return rows in both case. Version is 11g. I added another example above where the aggregate is causing the problem.

Comment: Add a non unique index on the b.a_id field. 'Poof' results are gone on your second query.

Comment: This must be a bug with your version: I tested it on 9.2.0.5 and 11.2.0.3.0 and the two queries return the same result.

Comment: It looks very much like bug #13074262 on Metalink. Are you in 11.2.0.1?

Comment: 11.1.0.6.0 64 bit. So even with the index you can't reproduce the problem?

Comment: Nope, can't reproduce the problem on the two versions I tried. Adding an index should never modify the result of a query, this is clearly a bug.

Comment: I tried it in version 11.1.0.6 and it has the problem. Tried it on verrsion 11.2.0.1 and it works (doens't have the problem). Are you saying the bug is in version 11.2.0.1 because that is the one where I can't reproduce the problem.

Comment: There are thousands of bugs listed on the support site, I probably didn't find the right one. Now that you have a test case you should contact support.

Answer (score 2):

Actually yes, both of the queries you provided are supposed to wrok the same way, but if i understand your need well, you are trying to select the fd_customer_key which has no Order?

I suggest the following query for your need, its more simple and less consuming :

```
SELECT a.fd_customer_key
  FROM FETCH_CUSTOMER a
 WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
          FROM fetch_customer_order b
         WHERE a.fd_customer_key = b.fd_customer_key)
```

Comment: +1 because it doesn't use the weird, old and error-prone `(+)` syntax. +2 because it uses a `EXISTS` instead of a `COUNT(*)` as it will probably be better for performance. The OP needs to find if a related row exists or not. No need for counting if there are 1,2,3 or 65042 related rows.

Comment: This is a better way to do it but we are just trying to illustrate an unexpected issue we are finding with Oracles query optimization.

Comment: @john: *"unexpected issue"* has high correlation with *"weird, old and error-prone `(+)` syntax"*

Comment: @ypercube: This has nothing to do with the old join syntax. Same thing has been replicated using join keywords.

Comment: @jcourtjr: Can you post the example query?